# Unable to create DescriptorMatcher in openCV 3.2 - Android

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, android

I'm running the following openCV code in Android:

```
FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
DescriptorExtractor descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);
DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);
```

It works fine in openCV 2.4.1
In openCV 3.2 I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorMatcher.create_1(int) (tried Java_org_opencv_features2d_DescriptorMatcher_create_11 and Java_org_opencv_features2d_DescriptorMatcher_create_11__I)
                                                                                     at org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorMatcher.create_1(Native Method)
                                                                                     at org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.java:76)
```

I checked it on 2 different Android devices. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in the new openCV version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently a problem with the OpenCV Manager on Google Play. I doesn't support version 3.2 yet. To overcome the problem I copied the libs directory (sdk\native\libs) from the SDK to src/main/jniLibs of my application. Please note that I'm using Android Studio. In Eclipse it supposed to be located under the root of the app. see: [Error while loading Native Library in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072187/error-while-loading-native-library-in-android)

Comment: Even worse, I still have the same problem with the 3.1.0 version

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right, i've tried it on my OpenCV 3.1 project and it's working flawlessly.
I don't know about OpenCV 3.2 but it should be the same. Have you tried to enter the corresponding int value of your matcher ?

```
DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(4);
```

You can find the corresponding Int values here [DescriptorMatcher OpenCV 3.2](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/db/d39/classcv_1_1DescriptorMatcher.html). It looks like `DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING` is considered as a long insted of int.

Comment: Yes, its working with 3.1 but but not working with 3.2
There's a bug in the new version

Comment: the value is int and not long