# OpenCV and Android - Feautre Making with FLANN

Tags: android, opencv

My code is bugged with an error at this line of code:

```
matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);
```

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorMatcher.create_1(int) (tried Java_org_opencv_features2d_DescriptorMatcher_create_11 and Java_org_opencv_features2d_DescriptorMatcher_create_11__I)
                                                   at org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorMatcher.create_1(Native Method)
```

In case someone needs to see my source here it is:

```
package com.example.qwill.opencvtests;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.audiofx.AudioEffect;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.KeyPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfDMatch;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfKeyPoint;
import org.opencv.features2d.*;

import org.opencv.features2d.Feature2D;
import org.opencv.features2d.FeatureDetector;

import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.photo.Photo;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.utils.Converters;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;

import org.opencv.features2d.FlannBasedMatcher;
import org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorExtractor;
import org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorMatcher;
import org.opencv.features2d.FeatureDetector;
import org.opencv.features2d.Features2d;


import java.io.File;
import java.util.Vector;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BFMatcher descriptorMatcher;

    FeatureDetector test;

    FeatureDetector detector;
    DescriptorExtractor descriptor;
    DescriptorMatcher matcher;


    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    Log.d("TEST", "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    test = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.FAST); //feature detector goes here!

                    MatOfKeyPoint one = new MatOfKeyPoint();
                    MatOfKeyPoint two = new MatOfKeyPoint();
                    MatOfKeyPoint done = new MatOfKeyPoint();
                    MatOfKeyPoint dtwo = new MatOfKeyPoint();

                    Mat image1, image2;


                    image1 = Highgui.imread(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.one, null).toString());

                    image2 = Highgui.imread(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.two, null).toString());

                    Mat imageOut = image1.clone();

                    test.detect(image1, one);
                    test.detect(image2, two);

                    DescriptorExtractor extractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(2);
                    Mat descriptors1;
                    extractor.compute(image1, one, done);
                    extractor.compute(image2, two, dtwo);

                    matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);

                    MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();


                   matcher.match(image1, image2, matches);
                    Features2d.drawMatches(image1, one, image2, two, matches, imageOut);

                    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageOut.cols(), imageOut.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Utils.matToBitmap(imageOut, bm);

                    Log.d("TEST", "  worked !!!! " );
                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("TEST", "here");

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d("OpenCV", "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync("3.2.0", this, mLoaderCallback);
        } else {
            Log.d("TEST", "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }
    }
}
```

The difference between my posts and other posts is that I haven't resolved my issue with the other post!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to create DescriptorMatcher in openCV 3.2 - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788433/unable-to-create-descriptormatcher-in-opencv-3-2-android)

Comment: This is not a duplicate: that solution *did not* work for me.

Comment: Have you tried both?

Comment: Yes I tried both, neither work.